# Recent Activity default duration still unusable

Tags: support, recent-activity

I know this has been posted several times [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65309/recent-activity-page-getting-less-usable).  Lots of posts about it, and lots of [status-complete].

This image shows a default recent activity duration of 8 minutes and 49 seconds.  I had not clicked any page in the SE network for 7ish hours.  (unless I sleep-surfed the net.)

[image]

---

This image shows a duration of **6 seconds**!!  I'd been browsing SO and other sites in the network, but hadn't clicked a page on SO in several minutes (though I can't verify the times on this one).

[image]

---

Is it something in the way I'm browsing the SE network?  Could it be that I have the [Stack Overflow Notifier](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/djioipahfnmmhddmnanoicecpnfomned) extension and that is conflicting?  I did disable it for awhile but still had issues with the duration.

Comment: I've got almost a day on my Gaming envelope; if I were to click on it again, it would then reset to right now. I would guess that it is some app or extension which is causing this to reset for you without you actually visiting the page. That, or maybe you are sleep-surfing.

Comment: @Grace, I still see the issue with my extension disabled.  I had not viewed the recent activity page 6 seconds ago when that was the duration it showed me.

Comment: What does your envelope report if you are to go to [your envelope at stats](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/recent/1142/ "I think this should be right. I might have missed, though")?

Comment: @Grace, Duration since the 17th.  |:

Comment: Well, looks like it isn't any kind of app or extension - you're sleep-surfing (or some otherwise unknowing equivalent). Should get that checked out. ♪

Comment: @Grace, *pretty* sure that isn't the issue. (;

Comment: I just bookmarked the "today" page and click that instead... much more useful.

Comment: All I want is the TODAY list... it's not like that much happens in one day that I need to see a smaller portion of time.